# How do I send login credentials to a 301 redirect page from a wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, redirect, dns, credentials

I have a wordpress site with a login plugin installed. In the public_html folder, I've added a folder for a page with a chatbot.
I couldn't find a way to bring this chatbot page under the login in the main site and so created a 301 redirect to the chatbot page from an existing page that came under the login. This let me hide the chatbot option on the site from logged out users.
How do I access the user credentials ( specifically the username) in the redirect?

I initially added a short code to extract the username from the URL after login. I was planning to store this in the browser and add a link to the chatbot page where I could then use the stored username. But localStorage didn't accept the chatbot page as the same domain as the WordPress site.

Is there a way to send the username to the redirected page or is there a better way to set up this structure?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this helps https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39662/how-to-validate-a-user-from-ouside-wordpress-php

Comment: @IronMan Thank you. I was looking for a way to basically send a string from the logged in wordpress page to the chatbot to store each user's conversation with their username. The link suggested didn't seem to address this, I think.